# A date picker without year

Tags: datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to modify the [jqueryui date picker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) to work and look like the one [in this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzqAz.jpg). How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [JqueryUI Date Picker documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-yearRange) mentions a setting called `yearRange` that can be used to do this.

The value is supposed to be the min and max year allowed.

So, for your usecase, only allow current year in the range.

```
$( ".my-date-selector" ).datepicker({
  yearRange: "2021:2021"
});
```

or a future proof answer will be

```
let year = new Date().getFullYear();
$( ".my-date-selector" ).datepicker({
  yearRange: `${year}:${year}`
});
```

Comment: I tried it, it [doesn't work](https://jsfiddle.net/gtzavx32/)

Comment: @loan , updated my answer using another format allowed according to the docs, tested and working.